# Magento Inner Join and Ordering

Tags: mysql, magento, join

On Magento catalog page, there's a join attached to collection. The join works perfectly.

```
$products->joinTable(
    array('as_name' => 'some_table'),
    'product_id=entity_id',
    array('some_var' => 'variable'),
    array('store_id' => array('eq' => '1')),
    'inner'
);
```

If I was to run the query raw, `some_var` column will have correct values. Also, if I add `ORDER BY some_var DESC` raw, it will order correctly. However, if I use Magento's `$products->setOrder('some_var', 'desc');` the query Magento submits becomes:

```
ORDER BY `e`.`some_var` DESC
```

How do I get Magento to not add `"e"` ? some_var is not part of that select, and should be `as_name`.

Comment: Since you have changed all your alias and column names, it's a bit hard to be certain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out:
`$collection->getSelect()->order('some_var DESC');`

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that if the alias you specify for the joined column is in fact the same as a column in the base table you will run into a problem.

addAttributeToSort() checks for the column in _joinFields first and if it is found (which it would be in your case) it then calls out to _getAttributeFieldName() to resolve the alias into a fully qualified column reference. _getAttributeFieldName() checks for the alias in _staticFields BEFORE it checks in _joinFields.  This means if you have a conflict, the base table columns win.

```
public function addAttributeToSort($attribute, $dir='asc')
{
    if (isset($this->_joinFields[$attribute])) {
        $this->getSelect()->order($this->_getAttributeFieldName($attribute).' '.$dir);
        return $this;
    }
    if (isset($this->_staticFields[$attribute])) {
        $this->getSelect()->order("e.{$attribute} {$dir}");
    }
    if (isset($this->_joinAttributes[$attribute])) {
        $attrInstance = $this->_joinAttributes[$attribute]['attribute'];
        $entityField = $this->_getAttributeTableAlias($attribute).'.'.$attrInstance->getAttributeCode();
    } else {
        $attrInstance = $this->getEntity()->getAttribute($attribute);
        $entityField = 'e.'.$attribute;
    }
    if ($attrInstance) {
        if ($attrInstance->getBackend()->isStatic()) {
            $this->getSelect()->order($entityField.' '.$dir);
        } else {
            $this->_addAttributeJoin($attribute, 'left');
            if (isset($this->_joinAttributes[$attribute])) {
                $this->getSelect()->order($attribute.' '.$dir);
            } else {
                $this->getSelect()->order($this->_getAttributeTableAlias($attribute).'.value '.$dir);
            }
        }
    }
    return $this;
}

protected function _getAttributeFieldName($attributeCode)
{
    if (isset($this->_joinAttributes[$attributeCode]['condition_alias'])) {
        return $this->_joinAttributes[$attributeCode]['condition_alias'];
    }
    if (isset($this->_staticFields[$attributeCode])) {
        return sprintf('e.%s', $attributeCode);
    }
    if (isset($this->_joinFields[$attributeCode])) {
        $attr = $this->_joinFields[$attributeCode];
        return $attr['table'] ? $attr['table'] .'.'.$attr['field'] : $attr['field'];
    }

    $attribute = $this->getAttribute($attributeCode);
    if (!$attribute) {
        throw Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', Mage::helper('eav')->__('Invalid attribute name: %s.', $attributeCode));
    }

    if ($attribute->isStatic()) {
        if (isset($this->_joinAttributes[$attributeCode])) {
            $fieldName = $this->_getAttributeTableAlias($attributeCode).'.'.$attributeCode;
        } else {
            $fieldName = 'e.'.$attributeCode;
        }
    } else {
        $fieldName = $this->_getAttributeTableAlias($attributeCode).'.value';
    }
    return $fieldName;
}
```

**NB**: All this is on the assumption of Magento 1.5 as you didn't list your version